# How do I decode a JSON result to extract key names?

Tags: php, json

Below is the result of a JSON API call:

```
[{"title":"Teqpad.com|| Find Pageviews,Visits,Visitors,Unique Visitors,Website Worth...","url":"http:\/\/www.teqpad.com\/","top_tags":{"analytics":64,"statistics":57,"tools":43,"seo":41,"traffic":40,"search":22,"web":20,"blog":18,"blogging":14,"website":13}}]
```

I want to extract only `top_tags` for example:

```
analytics,statistics,tools,seo,traffic,search
```

How do I do this with `json_decode()`?

Comment: If I remember correctly google analytics uses a weird flavor of json. Edit: Maybe you're not using GA, but it's still invalid if you run it through a json validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$top_tags = array_keys($obj[0]['top_tags']);
print_r($top_tags);
```

Working example: http://codepad.org/QWjQQ097

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is malformed, the `top_tags` key references a malformed object (keys, but no values) - it should reference an array, like this:

```
[{"title":"Teqpad.com|| Find Pageviews,Visits,Visitors,Unique Visitors,Website  Worth...","url":"http:\/\/www.teqpad.com\/","top_tags":["analytics","statistics","tools","seo","traffic","search","web","blog","blogging","website"]}
```

You'd then parse it using the following code:

```
$json = ...
$obj = json_decode($json);
$top_tags = $obj[0]->top_tags;
print_r($top_tags);
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/An0ubOUG)

Comment: so is there any other way around??

Comment: ok fine now getting it ...but how do I extract these words from array??

Comment: @aron n Please modify your original question.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin I have modified and added some additional input to tag..this is final and no further changes